# О принципе работы long-polling, socket

Tags: сокет, long-poll

1. Заголовок keep-alive... Когда браузер отправляет запрос через ajax, то сервер (apache) не закрывает соединение на протяжении 5 секунд. Так вот, соединение на протяжении этого времени считается открытым, а почему тогда при повторной отправке браузер опять
   формирует заголовки и прочее? В чем    разница? Дело в том, что если    браузер и сервер не закрывают    соединение на протяжении 5 секунд,    тогда зачем заморачиваться
   long-polling? Какое тогда между    двумя этим запросами отличие? Помимо того, что с long-polling    результат придет быстрее.
2. В предыдущем вопросе я упомянул    long-polling, хотя особо не
   представляю, как он работает. Пример:    у меня имеется чат и сообщения
   которые хранятся в БД, то-есть,    браузер отправляет запрос на сервер,
   где сам запрос в БД (для проверки    новых сообщений) помещен в
   бесконечный цикл, и если новые данные    имеются, после этого сервер
   осуществляет ответ. Я правильно    понял принцип? А не ляжет ли сервер
   от такого "Бесконечного" количества    запросов в БД, ну, предположим, я буду
   отправлять цикл в сон каждые 500    миллисекунд, но тем не менее. Как в
   идеале это должно работать?
3. Сокеты работают по такому же    принципу (я имею в виду проверки    новых данных), как я описал во втором    вопросе?
4. Сколько максимум может длиться (по    времени) запрос AJAX (версия    HTTP/1.1). Ну, к примеру, если на    сервере установить sleep на 20    минут. Это вообще нормально столько
   времени не закрывать соединения?    Каждый браузер ведет себя по-разному? Пробовал в гугл хром 38    версия, соединения держится более 10    минут, а дольше не пробовал.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. при keep-alive в одном подключении просто несколько полноценных запросов. Они как бы "независимы". Просто время на установление подключения для мелких запросов занимает существенное время. При long-pulling запрос уходит, а ответ приходит позже. (в первом случае сервер присылает ответ сразу и не ждет).
2. Сервер не обязан опрашивать базу каждые пол секунды. Плюс могут применяться различные оптимизации.

   > А не ляжет ли сервер от такого "Бесконечного" количество запросов в БД

   а это зависит от Вашего кода. База может лечь и от одного запроса. А может обслуживать тысячи запросов в секунду.
3. с сокетами все проще. И keepalive, и longpolling работают поверх http (обычно). А http работает поверх сокетов. Поэтому через сокеты можно сделать перечисленное выше, так и сделать другими методами.

4. > Сколько максимум может длиться (по времени) запрос AJAX (версия HTTP/1.1).

   В теории - бесконечно. Я не видел ограничений

   > Ну, к примеру, если на сервере установить sleep на 20 минут. Это вообще нормально столько времени не закрывать соединения?

   Да, если это нужно.

   > Каждый браузер ведет себя по разному? Пробовал в гугл хром 38 версия, соединения держится более 10 минут, а дольше не пробовал.

   Да, это все сильно браузерозависимо.

Answer (score 4):

1. `Keep-alive` в HTTP/1.0 экономит клиенту время на поднятие соединения, а серверу - ресурсы на прием соединения. Разные серверы дают разный таймаут на `Keep-Alive`.
2. Да там в некотором роде "бесконечный цикл". Но вас ведь не смущает, что все запущенные программы на вашем компьютере находятся в бесконечном цикле. И нет нужды дергать БД непрерывно. Да и не обязательно текущие сообщения чата вообще держать в БД.
3. Да, общая схема такая. Вычитывание данных -> Реакция.
4. Опять-таки у разных браузеров разные дефолтные значения таймаутов.